# Progress OpenEdge Database string_agg equivalent

Tags: openedge

I am looking for a way to get a text field in OpenEdge to aggregate itself in a string much like PostgreSQL's string_agg functions. Does an equivalent exist in Progress OpenEdge without using abl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of OpenEdge SQL functions can be found here:

https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-sql-reference-117/page/OpenEdge-SQL-Functions.html

STRING_AGG is not included and I don't see anything that looks even remotely similar.

Comment: Also https://community.progress.com/s/article/000043717 "No, Progress' SQL-92 implementation does not support the GROUP_CONCAT keyword. GROUP_CONCAT is not part of the SQL-92 standard."

Comment: Thank you for answering this. I feel if someone (myself included) is searching google for this answer. At least they will get a very clear `IT CAN'T BE DONE` when they click the link to this question.